# Getting JSON data from Grails backend using Angularjs

Tags: java, json, http, angularjs, grails

I have the following problem. I have controller in Grails, which returns list in Json format:

```
render([tweets: tweets.take(2).collect { tweet -> [id: tweet.id, content: tweet.tweetContent]}] as JSON)
```

This is my UrlMapping:

```
"/tweets/"(controller: "tweets", parseRequest: true) {
        action = [GET: "list"]
```

So when I just open this url in any browser, I am getting list of elements in JSON format:

```
{"tweets":[{"id":375238019298914304,"content":"@RonNegrita @Paolah_96 jajajajajajajajaja pues ale Negrita q nos lo has xk este del Tuit prima JAJAJAHAHAHAHA"},{"id":375238020360048640,"content":"My 38 Life Goals for next 10 years. Brewery's, Alabama Football, Concerts, Companies, Kids, Fiji, & more: http://t.co/behxfnCo5t"}]}
```

Then I am trying to get this elements in HTML page using Angularjs. This is my simple code for html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app id="ng-app">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script>
function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
{
$scope.tweets = []
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/trutto-api/tweets/').success(function(data)
{
$scope.tweets = data; // response data 
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax"> 
<li ng-repeat="tweet in tweets>{{tweet.id}} - {{tweet.content}}</li>
</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to get data in Chrome browser, I am getting to following error:

```
"Xml http request cannot load http://localhost:8080/trutto-api/tweets/. Original null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin"
```

I found question regarding this error here, it suggests starting Chrome with this command:

```
"- allow-file-access-from-files".
```

I tried it - it doens't work, returns the same error.
Then I tried it on Glassfish server -> opening in Chrome leads to same error.

Opening in Mozilla Firefox leads to the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data.
```

How should I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.tweets = data.tweets;` in the success callback?

Comment: Tried to change, get the same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a CORS issue.  Use [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cors) to solve the issue.  Basically, the way you have your local dev setup, the ajax call thinks you're calling a different origin (domain) for the request and that isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I get JSON object, it is not shown on html page, but this is another issue :)